# Passport: Authentication not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication, passport.js

I am new to NodeJS. I am made a basic CRUD app with authentication using express. Sign up was successful but login is not successful.I am using passport and bcryptjs for authentication.

Here is home route. As index is called automatically so this is not getting called. For other routes it works only if manually pass the function `ensureAuthenticated` to their parameters just like below. I want it to work for all endpoints without manually doing so.

```
app.get("/", ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

Below is the login functionality.

```
app.get("/login", function (req, res) {
    const loginPath = path.join(__dirname, '/login.html');
    res.sendFile(loginPath);
});

passport.use(new localStrategy({
        usernameField: 'adminUsername',
        passwordField: 'password',
        session: false
    },
    function (adminUsername, password, done) {
        Admin.getAdminByAdminUsername(adminUsername, function (err, admin) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('getAdmin called');
            if (!admin) {
                console.log('Admin Not Found');
                return done(null, false);
            }

            Admin.comparePassword(password, admin.password, function (err, isMatch) {
                console.log('comparePassword called');
                if (err) throw err;
                if (isMatch) {
                    return done(null, admin);
                } else {
                    console.log('Wrong Password!');
                    return done(null, false);
                }
            });
        });
    }));

passport.serializeUser(function (admin, done) {
    done(null, admin.id);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    Admin.getAdminById(id, function (err, admin) {
        done(err, admin);
        console.log('findById called');
    });
});

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/login'}), function(req, res){
        console.log('login called');
        res.redirect('/');
    });

app.get('/logout', function(req,res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/login');
});

function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next){
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/login');
    }
}
```

**The problem is even without authentication, I still have access via URL endpoints.**

Here is the Admin schema file.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
   adminEmail: {
       type: String,
       unique: true,
       required: true
   },
   adminUsername:{
       type: String,
       unique: true,
       required: true
   },
   password:{
       type: String,
       required: true
   }
});

const Admin = mongoose.model('Admin', schema);
module.exports = Admin;

module.exports.getAdminByAdminUsername = function (adminUsername, callback) {
    const query = {adminUsername: adminUsername};
    Admin.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getAdminById = function (adminId, callback) {
    Admin.findById(adminId, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function (password, hash, callback) {
    bcrypt.compare(password, hash, function (err, isMatch) {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

Comment: `passport.use(new localStrategy( function (adminUsername, password, done)`
The problem starts here by default the passport defines as name the `username` and the `password`, for different name you must rename using the `usernameField` , `passwordField` 
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local

Comment: @AMS I couldn't find the error for some days. Thanks man, you saved me.

Comment: We are here to help

Comment: @AMS one other problem is that it is not redirect to login page if not logged in. How to fix it, have a look again, I updated the code.

Comment: This is due to a login route after other hours, you must do before all other routes, so that it is loaded before. Example: 
`app.get('/home')
app.get('/login')` 
That way if you create a rule on the `/home` page to redirect to `/login`, an error will occur because login has not yet been loaded.